# mysql_assoc error - displaying fine

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

i have an error being drawn with this code:

```
<?php
    include "config.inc.php";
        mysql_query($addClient) or die(mysql_error());
    $sth = mysql_query(
        sprintf(
            "SELECT c_id,p_id,p_title FROM projects WHERE c_id = %s",
            mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])
        )
    );
    $projects = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
        $projects[] = array('id' => $r['p_id'], 'name' => $r['p_title']);
    }
    print json_encode($projects);
    exit;


?>
```

I get this error:

> **Warning**:  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in **/home/content/g/a/t/gatts316/html/clients/inc/get-projects.php** on line **10**
>
> []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you changed mysql_fetch_assoc to mysql_fetch_array for testing... Anyway, the error should still persist.

You forgot to enclose the string %s in your query between '':

```
$sth = mysql_query(
    sprintf(
            "SELECT c_id,p_id,p_title FROM projects WHERE c_id = '%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])
    )
);
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick..thank you for the help!

Appreciate it.

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that is the right code? The error is referring to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` but there is no `mysql_fetch_assoc()` in the code you pasted. Where is `$addClient` defined? Perhaps something inside `config.inc.php` is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

there is no mysql_fetch_assoc on above code, are you sure that was snippet code from **get-projects.php**?