# Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql

I get the error when trying to run this:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/DbConnector.php');
$connector = new DbConnector();
$result = $connector->query('SELECT title,content FROM staff_vacancies ORDER BY ordering LIMIT 0,100');
// Get an array containing the results.
// Loop for each item in that array
while ($row = $connector->fetchArray($result)){

echo $row['title'].'</h3>';
echo $row['content'];
}
?>
```

I have a linked file: DbConnector.php:

```
<?php
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Class: DbConnector
// Purpose: Connect to a database, MySQL version
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
require_once 'SystemComponent.php';

class DbConnector extends SystemComponent {

var $theQuery;
var $link;

//*** Function: DbConnector, Purpose: Connect to the database ***
function DbConnector(){

    // Load settings from parent class
    $settings = SystemComponent::getSettings();

    // Get the main settings from the array we just loaded
    $host = $settings['dbhost'];
    $db = $settings['dbname'];
    $user = $settings['dbusername'];
    $pass = $settings['dbpassword'];

    //the settings
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'xxx';
    $user = 'xxx';
    $pass = 'xxx';

    // Connect to the database
    $this->link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($db);
    register_shutdown_function(array(&$this, 'close'));

}

//*** Function: query, Purpose: Execute a database query ***
function query($query) {
    $this->theQuery = $query;
    return mysql_query($query, $this->link);
}

//*** Function: getQuery, Purpose: Returns the last database query, for debugging ***
function getQuery() {
    return $this->theQuery;
}

//*** Function: getNumRows, Purpose: Return row count, MySQL version ***
function getNumRows($result) {
    return mysql_num_rows($result);
}

//*** Function: fetchArray, Purpose: Get array of query results ***
function fetchArray($result) {
    return mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

//*** Function: close, Purpose: Close the connection ***
function close() {
    mysql_close($this->link);
}


}
?>
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 18):

Your query must have a problem which is causing $result to be an invalid resource.

Try checking for [mysql_error()](https://www.php.net/mysql_error) after the line on which you run your query.

Edit:

In fact, I would alter your DBConnector class function query() to something like the following, so that an identifiable error is thrown when you have a bad query:

```
function query($query) {
    $this->theQuery = $query;
    $queryId = mysql_query($query,$this->link);
    if (! $queryId) {
        throw new Exception(mysql_error().".  Query was:\n\n".$query."\n\nError number: ".mysql_errno();
    }
    return $queryId;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I find this in a post, to me solved my problem.
Slds.

Yeah, Answer is simple, the query used is not a true result as it's a query inside of a getrow so to speak..
Here is the fix:
Find all lines that look like this:

```
mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("...snip...";-) );
```

And just add a "@" in front of it so it looks like this:

```
@mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("...snip...";-) );
```

Then do the same thing for the following lines..
Code:

```
mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("...snip...";-) );
```

Perform the same steps as above by adding the "@" to it so it looks like this:

```
@mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("...snip...";-) );
```

All this does it say "While doing xxx within yyy" Otherwise, it's dead due to missing result value. It's a PHP thing..

Works like a charm, took me 5 mins to rip the whole code apart and slap it all into Modernbill, Shares the same database and works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

This error means your query failed. **`mysql_query()`** returns false if an error occurred, you are then passing false to **`mysql_fetch_array()`** which is triggering the error message.

Your query could be failing due to a missing/wrong table or field. To see the detailed error, print out the result of **mysql_error()**.

The `mysql_*` library is deprecated. It is recommended to upgrade to **`MySQLi`** or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Load settings from parent class
$settings = SystemComponent::getSettings();

// Get the main settings from the array we just loaded
$host = $settings['dbhost'];
$db = $settings['dbname'];
$user = $settings['dbusername'];
$pass = $settings['dbpassword'];

//the settings
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'xxx';
$user = 'xxx';
$pass = 'xxx';
```

Did you mean to reassign the connection vars? OR was that a few lines of stub code you forgot to take out? Or just an example to show what $settings contains?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the error from mysql_error(). Without that I can only guess... try escaping your field names?

```
$result = $connector->query('SELECT `title`,`content` FROM `staff_vacancies` ORDER BY `ordering` LIMIT 0,100');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query must have a problem which is causing $result to be an invalid resource.

Use this

```
<?php
require_once('includes/DbConnector.php');
$connector = new DbConnector();
$result = $connector->query('SELECT title,content FROM staff_vacancies ORDER BY ordering LIMIT 0,100');
// Get an array containing the results.
// Loop for each item in that array

if($result){
while ($row = $connector->fetchArray($result)){

echo $row['title'].'</h3>';
echo $row['content'];
}
}
?>
```