# mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in php

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

```
$query  = "SELECT UniqueID FROM configuration";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { }
```

throwing exception as

> Warning: `mysql_fetch_assoc()`: supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\ehp\hello.php on line 10

Answer (score 1):

That's slightly confusing, since this sort of thing is usually caused by an SQL error, however the line `..or die(mysql_error());` should have picked that up. Check the contents of your loop that you're not overwriting the `$result` variable.