# mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I'm trying to set a simple cron script to do some database updating, and I'm pretty worthless with MySQL without ActiveRecord (I use CodeIgniter).  I keep getting the error message,

```
mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

with the following code:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("my_db") or die(mysql_error()); 
$query = "select visit_e_id, visit_e_type from visits";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error()." Actual query: ".$query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
     ....
}
```

Like I said, I'm not that great with straight PHP and MySQL (would appreciate any advice on how to include some sort of framework or ActiveRecords that could be used as part of a cron job).  Any thoughts?

Comment: doesn't it print out "Query failed: " error message? try `var_dump($result);` - the only other possible reason is  simple mistype

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858304/mysql-fetch-assoc-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource-in-ph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you assign mysql_connect as a variable and pass it in as a link identifier as a second parameter to the `mysql_select_db` and `query` functions?

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
// Check to see if valid connection
var_dump($db);

mysql_select_db("my_db", $db) or die(mysql_error()); 
$query = "select visit_e_id, visit_e_type from visits";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db)
or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error()." Actual query: ".$query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
     ....
}
```

Also ensure that you query syntax is correct and doesn't have misspelling or typos

Answer (score 1):

This error is pretty simple and self-explanatory - a $result variable has unexpected type.
Thus, you have to so some debugging. Add `var_dump($result);` before and inside loop and study the output.