# Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hell there
when i try and connect to pull thing out of the database i get the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/49/5548763/html/matt/download.php on line 17
```

None of the other answers on this site worked.

here is the script:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("XXXX", "name", "password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("nameofdb",$con);

$musictable = "";

$sql = "GET * FROM matt";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

$id = $row->id;

$name = $row->name;

$update = $row->update;

$length = $row->length;

$size = $row->size;

$musictable .= "
  <tr>
    <td width=\"63%\">".$name."</td>
    <td width=\"10%\">".$length." / ".$size."</td>
    <td width=\"10%\"><a href=\"download.php?mp3=".$name."\">DOWLOAD</a></td>
    <td width=\"17%\">|||||</td>
  </tr>
  ";
}

?>
```

Comment: Add this code just before the while loop: var_dump($result); and post it here

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858304/mysql-fetch-assoc-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource-in-ph)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because your query is wrong.

```
$sql = "GET * FROM matt";
```

must probably become

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM matt";
```

the basic measure to get warned about this is

```
if (!$result)
 die("mySQL error: ". mysql_error());
```

after issuing a query.

Comment: +1 for Pekka: this error usually occurs when you have a SQL syntax error.

Comment: WOW i feel like the biggest dumb-ass ever. I guess because i was working with $_GET earlier it stuck i cant believe i made that mistake and didn't even catch it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using 'SELECT' instead of 'GET'?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "GET * FROM matt";
```

is wrong. Correct SQL syntax is

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM matt";
```

That error is passed into

`$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);`

which then is invalid and can't be used in `while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))`.

You should check for `mysql_error()` after `mysql_query()` to catch these.

Answer (score 0):

Want to use SELECT *

You can also use

```
mysql_query($sql, $con) or die("Error in $sql:" . mysql_error($con));
```

If you don't want to use die() then you can use echo to see what the error was and help debug the application at least.