# mysql_num_rows and mysql_fetch_array error

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923101/warning-mysql-fetch-object-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-res)

I Get mysql_num_rows and mysql_fetch_array error in this code.. 
Warning: mysql_num_rows() supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in
/localhost/more_ajax.php on line 49

Warning: mysql_fetch_array()supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in
 /localhost/more_ajax.php on line 52

```
<?php ?>
<style type="text/css">


</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".more2").click(function() {
   var element = $(this);
   var blab = element.attr("id");
    $("#morebutton").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
  url: "more_ajax.php",
   data: "lastblab="+ blab,  
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){

 $("#load_updates").append(html);
 $(".more"+blab).remove();

  }
});



    return false;
    });
//---------------- Delete Button----------------


});
</script>

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","yay_website", "1234");
mysql_select_db("yay_data");


if(isSet($_POST['lastblab']))
{


$lastblab = $_POST['lastblab'];



$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blabbing where blab_id<'$lastblab' ORDER BY blab_id DESC limit 5");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql_check));
{

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_check));
{
$blab_id=$row['blab_id'];
$blab=$row['blab'];
?>

<div style="width:500px; height:50px">
  <div>

  <div class="con">
  <span style="padding:5px;">
<?php echo $blab; ?>

</span>
  </div>
  </div>





<?php } 
?>

  <span class="more<?php echo $blab_id; ?>" id="morebutton">
  <a id="<?php echo $blab_id; ?>" class="more2" title="Follow" href="#" style="color:#000">
               Mooore
               </a> </span>
<?php }}

?>
```

Comment: Did it not occur to you to search first?

Comment: Search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Warning%3A+mysql_fetch_array%28%29supplied+argument+is+not+a+valid+MySQL+result+resource

Comment: @deceze That is not my post..

Comment: No, but the problem is exactly the same!

Answer (score 0):

Its because the query is failing on line 48.

Try adding:

```
$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blabbing where blab_id<'$lastblab' ORDER BY blab_id DESC limit 5") or die(mysql_error());
```

It should show you what's going on :o)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Query failed
if (!$sql_check)
{
 die("mySQL error: ". mysql_error()); 
}
else  // Query executed 
{
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_check));
   {

      // Display Code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blabbing where blab_id < '".$lastblab."' ORDER BY blab_id DESC limit 5") or die(mysql_error());
```

**UPDATE**

remove `;` after `if` into your code, check below line

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql_check))
```

also remove `;` after `while` into your code, check below line

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_check))
```

Comment: Sorry.. Its Still Give An Error

Comment: check my updates, change your code and test it again