# mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have been trying to insert a sample piece of data from my form, but I always get a syntax error executing $result.

The relevant part from index.php:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
<ul >
    <li>
        <label for="accession_number">Accession Number</label>
        <input id="accession_number" name="accession_number" type="text" maxlength="6" value=""/> 
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

and parts from form.php:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die('Could not connect'.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $connection) or die("Cannot select db.");

$accession_number = $_POST['accession_number'];

$query = "INSERT INTO top (accession_number) ".
"VALUES ($accession_number)";
var_dump($query);
mysql_error();

$result = mysql_query($$query, connection) or die('Error querying database.');

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `var_dump($query);` + http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858304/mysql-fetch-assoc-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource-in-p)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your parameters for `mysql_query()` are in the wrong order.

This

```
$result = mysql_query($connection, $query)
```

should be

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

> resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier ] )

### Update

When I said use `mysql_error()`, I meant only if there was an apparent error. Try something like this

```
if (isset($_POST['accession_number'])) {
    $accession_number = $_POST['accession_number'];
    $query = sprintf('INSERT INTO `top` (accession_number) VALUES (%d)',
                     $accession_number);
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (false === $result) {
        throw new Exception('Error in query you have, hmmm: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    // and so on
```

I highly recommend ditching the MySQL library entirely and moving to PDO. Writing the above code makes me feel dirty.

Comment: +1. Correct, it goes QUERY, CONNECTION. You have them reversed. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Funny, my O'Reilly book tells me to do otherwise. Anyways, I followed your suggestion, and the error message disappears, but PhpMyAdmin doesn't show any entered data. After adding `var_dump($query);`, I get `string(48) "INSERT INTO primary (accession_number)VALUES (1)" Error querying database.`

Comment: @user Use `mysql_error()` to get the last error message. FYI "primary" is a reserved MySQL word. Either change your table name or wrap it in backticks. Which O'Reilly book is it?

Comment: @user Are you sure the book isn't using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) instead of MySQL?

Comment: Head First, PHP & MySQL. And you're right, they are using MySQLi. I changed back to MySQL because I was having connection trouble and wanted it working first. Error is now showing an unexpected T_VARIABLE for $result after changing table 'primary' to 'top'.

Comment: `mysql_close($connection);` is now generating a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`. Removing the line now fixes things.

Comment: Everything is working perfectly now! Thanks for the info on mysql and mysqli differences and with the reserved 'primary' word.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I'll take your advice on that after I have time to master the basics.