# mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$idc = $_GET['id'];
$name1 = $_GET['name'];
$id2 = $_GET['ids'];
$toplinks = "";

if (isset($_SESSION['category_id'])) {
    // Put stored session variables into local php variable
    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['name'];

}
$sql_2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blabbing WHERE mem_id='$userid' OR men_id='$idc' ORDER BY blab_date DESC LIMIT 20")

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_2)){
    }
```

Comment: provide the error code you are getting

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858304/mysql-fetch-assoc-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource-in-ph)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is an error in your query ... you refer to `mem_id` and then OR `men_id`

Try adding `or die ( mysql_error () );` to the mysql_query line.

i.e.

```
$sql_2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blabbing WHERE mem_id='$userid' OR mem_id='$idc' ORDER BY blab_date DESC LIMIT 20") or die ( mysql_error () );
```

Comment: +1 consider escaping the values first, SQL injection is the easiest thing to prevent do and the easiest thing to forget

Comment: The original post was not about preventing SQL injection in the script.  Yes escaping the or pre-validation of parameters is the right thing to do, especially here, but it is outside of the scope of the OP's question.  And I only modified a snippet of the script, not the entirety.

Comment: you suggest to scape the variable to avoid injection ?

Comment: Since the two variables going into the query are ids, I am going to assume that they are numeric.  That said, there isn't a need to escape them, just make sure the values are numbers ... i.e. `$idc = intval ( $_GET [ 'id' ] );` That will suffice because it makes sure that `$idc` is numeric before putting it into the query.

Answer (score 1):

Did you `mysql_connect` first?

Comment: I did everything is coneccting the only thing is I want to display comments under two condition that user is log out or log in