# Mysql_fetch_array supplied argument is not a valid MYSQL result

Tags: php, mysql

How do I fix the "Mysql_fetch_array supplied argument is not a valid MYSQL result" error?

This is the code that had the error:

```
<?php
    require "connect.php";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT author, date 
                            FROM articles 
                           WHERE id = ' . $id . '") or die(mysql_error());
    $runrows = mysql_fetch_array('$query');

     $author = $runrows['author'];
     $date = $runrows['date'];        
?>
```

Comment: Looks like an SQL injection point :) (Just a guess and totally off topic, just want to warn you :) )

Comment: ooo i've heard alot about that. how do i fix that?

Comment: You may want to check about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [Security measures to be followed in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Short answer: `WHERE id = " .((int)$id)` and also see my presentation http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858304/mysql-fetch-assoc-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource-in-ph)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT author, date FROM articles WHERE id = ' . $id . '") or die(mysql_error());
  $runrows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

There should be no quotes for `$query`. Its a variable, not a string.

Comment: +1 Right, in fact `$query` is a resource, therefore it makes no sense to make it part of an expression or interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$runrows = mysql_fetch_array('$query');
```

Should be

```
$runrows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

or

```
$runrows = mysql_fetch_array("$query");
```

Using `'$variable'` just prints out `$variable` as text. You want to use the value of the variable.

SQL Injection is when you use that `$id` variable from user interaction.

E.g. you have the following URL:

http://example.com/articles.php?id=1

If you just add the `id` variable to your query people can inject code in the variable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

To prevent this you can simply do: 
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);

Or use prepared statements if it is supported.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statements#Parameterized_statements

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dots and use something like this in the third line

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT author, date FROM articles WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me when I had not closed the connection using mysql_close($conn).  I guess the socket between from the db was still open, and next time when i again connected to the same db, this particular error came.  There were no other issues.  Once I explicitly closed the connection and then again restarted the connection, this issue was resolved.  Hope it helps.