# PHP: Trouble using mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to return results from my database so that I can create an XML file for use in Adobe Flex, where I will then populate a Google Map. At the moment using Charles i'm getting the following error `mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

Here is the code for my function:

```
public function getBusiness ($item)
{
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,

    "SELECT * FROM businesses");

    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    $row = "";

    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><map>";

    while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt)) !== false)
    {
        echo "<business><businessid>" . $row["businessid"] . "</businessid>";
        echo "<type>" . $row["type"] . "</type>";
        echo "<name>" . $row["name"] . "</name>";
        echo "<street>" . $row["street"] . "</street>";
        echo "<city>" . $row["city"] . "</city>";
        echo "<country>" . $row["country"] . "</country>";
        echo "<postcode>" . $row["postcode"] . "</postcode>";
        echo "<latitude>" . $row["latitude"] . "</latitude>";
        echo "<longitude>" . $row["longitude"] . "</longitude>";
        echo "<phonenumber>" . $row["phonenumber"] . "</phonenumber>";
        echo "<email>" . $row["email"] . "</email>";
        echo "<website>" . $row["website"] . "</website>";
        echo "<logo>" . $row["logo"] . "</logo>";
        echo "<description>" . $row["description"] . "</description>";
        echo "<datesubmitted>" . $row["datesubmitted"] . "</datesubmitted></business>";
    }
    echo "</map>";


}
```

Can anybody help at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858304/mysql-fetch-assoc-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource-in-p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)() instead of mysql_fetch_assoc()

Answer (score 5):

You are using `mysqli` for running the statement, then trying to process the result as `mysql`? Yeah, that's not going to work.

Use functions from the same extension! They are not cross-compatible.

Comment: Well I apologise for being new to this and asking for help. Thanks for letting me know, though.