# php warning mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to access some information from mysql, but am getting the  warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource for the second line of code below, any help would be much appreciated.

```
$musicfiles=getmusicfiles($records['m_id']);
$mus=mysql_fetch_assoc($musicfiles);
for($j=0;$j<2;$j++)
{
 if(file_exists($mus['musicpath']))
 {
  echo '<a href="'.$mus['musicpath'].'">'.$mus['musicname'].'</a>';       
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'Hello world';     
 }
}

function getmusicfiles($m_id)
{
$music="select * from music WHERE itemid=".$s_id;
$result=getQuery($music,$l);
return $result;
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `getmusicfiles()`?

Comment: And what's the definition of getQuery()? Is there a call to mysql_query in there, somewhere? If not, you will get the warning, as it should be.

Comment: yeah there is, and it works fine since I used it quite a bit in my site

Comment: @death the kid: If it worked fine, you wouldn't be asking this question ;) Can we see it?

Comment: Note that your parameter ($m_id) is not the same as the value you're trying to append to your SQL querty ($s_id) - perhaps this is your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

Answer (score 5):

Generally, the mysql_* functions are used as follows:

```
$id = 1234;
$query = 'SELECT name, genre FROM sometable WHERE id=' . $id;
// $query is a string with the MySQL query
$resource = mysql_query($query);
// $resource is a *MySQL result resource* - a mere link to the result set
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) { 
    // $row is an associative array from the result set
    print_r($row);
    // do something with $row
}
```

If you pass something to mysql_fetch_assoc that is not a MySQL result resource (whether it's a string, an object, or a boolean), the function will complain that it doesn't know what to do with the parameter; which is exactly what you are seeing.

**A common gotcha**: you get this warning if you pass something (other than a valid query string) to `mysql_query`:

```
$id = null;
$query = 'SELECT name, genre FROM sometable WHERE id=' . $id;
$res = mysql_query($query); 
// $res === FALSE because the query was invalid
// ( "SELECT name, genre FROM sometable WHERE id=" is not a valid query )
mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
// Warning: don't know what to do with FALSE, as it's not a MySQL result resource
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code of getmusicfiles there's not a lot we can really help you with.  You should be returning a valid mysql resource in that function.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you need to return a valid mysql resource into the mysql_fetch_assoc function to retrieve the next row.  For example:

```
$sql = "select * from table";

$resultSet = mysql_query($sql) or die("Couldn't query the database.");
echo "Num Rows: " . mysql_num_rows($resultSet);

while ($resultRowArr = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSet)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly `getmusicfiles() does`. It must return a result of `mysql_query()` function call, then it will be a "valid MySQL result".

And you most probably wanted to put the line `$mus=mysql_fetch_assoc($musicfiles)` inside of the `for` cycle to fetch several rows one after another.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify what the function `getQuery()`

```
$result=getQuery($music,$l);
```

does

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> function getmusicfiles($m_id) {
> $music="select * from music WHERE itemid=".$s_id;
> ```

`$m_id != $s_id` ?