# A weird mysql_fetch_(assoc,array,object) error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php warning mysql_fetch_assoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901457/php-warning-mysql-fetch-assoc)

I have a weird problem about my script. It returns always error for mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc. I have used mysql_fetch many times in my project and I checked for this error many times but I am blind about what is happening. Is there something wrong about my script?

My functions aim is learning the biggest value of specified mysql field.

Here is the function:

```
function nextIncrement($table,$field) {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT '$field' FROM '$table' ORDER BY '$field' DESC LIMIT 0,1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $next = $row[$field];
    }
    $next = (int)$next;
    return $next;
}
```

**Warning**:  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource ...

Comment: Seems like your SQL query is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most  likely, your `mysql_query()` returned false for some reason.

See [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for a list of possible values that `mysql_query()` can return.

Do a `echo mysql_error();` to see what's wrong.

Comment: Query works fine in sql editor but it returns error when I echo:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY 'fbUserReceipeId' DESC LIMIT 0,1' at line 1')' at line 1

Comment: @Ahmet try backticks in the table name: `\`` instead of `'`

Comment: Oh Pekka thank you very much. It worked. But what is the difference? And what is it's shortcut :)

Comment: @Ahmet backticks are used to quote table names

Comment: Weird thing is I used ' instead of backtick many times with no problem. Thank you. What is shortcut for backtick

Comment: @Ahmet I don't know, but are you sure it's not on your keyboard somewhere? It should be on the turkish layout as well, see e.g. http://frontype.com/keyboarding/540px-Computer-keyboard-Turkey.svg.png

Comment: Oh Pekka, you are life saver. I am sure %99,9 people never needed that key. It seems like a back comma on keyboard. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that the query actually succeeds before proceeding to fetch results.

Comment: Yeah it succeeds. It returns one row and one column as I wish. Everythinh seems OK, right?

Comment: How do you determine that it succeeds? Your function will return something in every case, the return will be 0 if there is no result or an error within the query.

Comment: I tested it writing table's and field's name directly. It was work everytime with ' but this time didn't. Pekka's solution which is using backticks worked. Thanks @Ignacio and @Dr.Molle for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an error in your SQL statement, or maybe you don't have an open database connection?