# Troubleshooting "mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

Tags: php, mysql, database, dbconnection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)
>   [php warning mysql_fetch_assoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901457/php-warning-mysql-fetch-assoc)

I am using PHP with a MySQL backend. When I try to connect to the database I am getting the following error.

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): 
>   supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource 
>   in /var/www/htdocs/somefile.php on line 18

Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Comment: No one can help you unless you post the actual code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need a proper MySQL connection, check your database settings make sure the database and tables exist.  Posting the code  could be helpful if your are still stuck, especially the mysql_connect() part or whatever function calls you are using to connect.