# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update table phpbb_points same phpbb_posts

This is my code

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    $link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpasswd) or die('Could not connect');

$db_id = mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Could not get db');
$d = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users ORDER BY id;"));

mysql_query("UPDATE phpbb_users SET `user_points`='".$d['user_posts']."' WHERE user_id='".$d['user_id']."';") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

But it return this

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in /home/******/public_html/forum/point.php on line 7

Please help me, thank in advance

Comment: can't see that function in the code.

Comment: You have `mysql_fetch_assoc()` in the code but not `mysql_fetch_array()` ?

Comment: Remove the semicolon `;` from the SQL. BTW mysql_fetch_assoc is a short-cut for mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: Where is the mysql_fetch_array statement in your code? Your usage of $d is also incorrect. It is an associative array! 
`while($d = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users ORDER BY id;")))` perform query

Comment: possible duplicate of [php warning mysql_fetch_assoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901457/php-warning-mysql-fetch-assoc)

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements. Note that `or die(mysql_error())` should never appear in production code, as [`die`](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die) breaks HTML output and database error messages should never be revealed to non-admin users as it [discloses too much information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2). A better approach would be to properly implement error handling.

Comment: Don't use [`SELECT *`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/321299/) unless you're writing a DB administration program; select only the columns you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `$d['user_posts']` in your second query. This is not valid, cause the first query will most likely return more than one row.

Comment: Yes i need to Update all user @@

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users ORDER BY id;"));
```

You are using (semicolon;) in the sql remove this (semicolon;) from the sql.

Correct one:

```
$d = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users ORDER BY id"));
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Sorry it not work, when i remove "ORDER BY id", MySQL dont return error, but it don't update with my request

Comment: Correct update query: mysql_query("UPDATE phpbb_users SET `user_points`='".$d['user_posts']."' WHERE user_id='".$d['user_id']."'") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

```
$d = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users ORDER BY id;");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($d) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE phpbb_users SET `user_points`='".$row['user_posts']."' WHERE user_id='".$row['user_id']."';") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**REMOVE  THE SEMI-COLON IN THAT QUERY**

//false code

```
$d = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users ORDER BY id;"));
```

//true code

```
$d = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users ORDER BY id"));
```

Comment: you  need check the mysql_fetch_array() error.....in mysql_fetch_assoc()....There is no error..or send the full coding