# Mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result …

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

I tried everything I could think of, but I keep on getting this error.

**Mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /url/ on line 41**

```
if ( $_POST[submit] == "Submit" )
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO table (`content`, `userid`, `ttime`) VALUES 
('$_POST[content]', '".$user_id."', '".time()."')";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$link) or die(mysql_error());
/* (line 41 is the following)*/ 
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    } }
```

I tried printing out the error (no error prints out just the warning), I tried changing the query, everything I could think of. The code works just fine - it does the insert on click, everything is fine, just that warning is appearing ._.'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From php [documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) on `mysql_query()`

> ### Return Values
>
> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN
>   and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a
>   resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> **For other type of SQL statements,
>   INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success
>   or FALSE on error.**
>
> The returned result resource should be
>   passed to mysql_fetch_array(), and
>   other functions for dealing with
>   result tables, to access the returned
>   data.
>
> Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how
>   many rows were returned for a SELECT
>   statement or mysql_affected_rows() to
>   find out how many rows were affected
>   by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or
>   UPDATE statement.
>
> mysql_query() will also fail and
>   return FALSE if the user does not have
>   permission to access the table(s)
>   referenced by the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can't fetch a result from an INSERT query.

Comment: Then how am I supposed to do it?

Comment: What exactly is "it" supposed to be?

Comment: >.<' Just re-read the mysql_fetch_assoc info and how it's used. Sorry and thanks >.< I thought it was supposed to be used with insert and select ><' *newb*

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to obtain a data row from a query that is not a SELECT query. You can only fetch associated arrays from a result data set. An INSERT query just does its thing.

Comment: Thank you, thought I should use it for both ><!