# Warning: mysql_error(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

```
        $err = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tridy (id,NazevTridy,url) VALUES (
            '$i',
            '$tridy->find('div[class=rozvrhseznam]', 0)->find('a[href]', $i)->outertext',
            '$tridy->find('div[class=rozvrhseznam]', 0)->find('a[href]', $i)->href')");
        mysql_error($err); // line 97
```

> Warning: mysql_error(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /hosting/www/cran-web.com/www/rozvrh/engine.php on line 97

--- lines 2-6:

```
$username="*****.com";
$password="*********";
$database="*********";
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', $username, $password) or die('Could not connect'.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Cannot select db.");
```

I'm getting this error when I try to execute my query. Can you tell what does the error message mean and how to fix it?

Comment: You should really save the mysql connection resource, returned by `mysql_connect` somewhere.

Comment: I know it might be obvious what you want us to do, but you could at least formulate a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_error()` expects a "Link resource" and no "result resource". Te correct way would be something like:

```
$username="*****.com";
$password="*********";
$database="*********";
$connection = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', $username, $password) or die('Could not connect'.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $connection) or die( "Cannot select db.");


$err = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tridy (id,NazevTridy,url) VALUES (
        '$i',
        '$tridy->find('div[class=rozvrhseznam]', 0)->find('a[href]', $i)->outertext',
        '$tridy->find('div[class=rozvrhseznam]', 0)->find('a[href]', $i)->href')", $connection);
mysql_error($connection); // line 97
```

Mind the use of `$connection`. Wile $connection could be dropped everywhere as in

```
mysql_error();
```

Which uses the last opened connection or opens a new one by default. While depending on the default connection is bad. You might also want to look into [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) as alternative ways to talk to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_error($err); remove the argument!
It takes link to the resource not number of error.

Link is used to recognise different connections (you can retrieve one using mysql_connect) read about this if u need more.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a query into mysql_error, you need to pass a link identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Also mind that [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) dealing with `INSERT` returns  `true` on success and `false` on failure.

So naming the variable `$err` is somehow misleading, `if($err)` would mean no error occurred and vice versa.

Better:

```
$success = mysq_query("INSERT....");

if(!$success) {
    // use of $connection is pointed to in other answers
    $error_msg = mysql_error($connection); 

    // so some error handling
}
```

About [`mysql_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php):

> **Parameter**: The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` is assumed

and the return value:

> Returns the error text from the last MySQL function, or '' (empty string) if no error occurred.

So you also **do** something with the return value. Just calling `mysql_error()` is of no use!