# What is corret way to connect to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

what is the correct way to connect to MySQL database without the mysql_fetch_assoc() error?

Getting [Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource] with 
mysql_connect('localhost', 'name', 'pass'); mysql_select_db('dbname');

getting mysql_fetch_assoc() error without mysql_select_db any suggest?

CODE are:

var somethings= ;

Comment: Post what you've tried already, you might be closer than you think.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate. What error are you experiencing?

Comment: Getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function msyql_select_db() with

mysql_connect('localhost', 'name', 'pass');
msyql_select_db('dbname');

getting mysql_fetch_assoc() error without mysql_select_db

any suggest?

Comment: `msyql_select_db` is misspelled. Try `mysql_select_db`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$result= mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT username FROM users'); 
$somethings= array(); 
while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $somethings[]= $row['something']; 
}
```

Basically changing $results to $result.

Comment: yep, but after im getting blank page, i checked source and this is showing.

Warning:  json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in line 17. any idea? thanks

Comment: If you look at line 17, you will see you have 2 parameters to the json_encode function. There should only be 1, the data you wish to encode.

Answer (score 2):

Typo? Your question has `msyql_select_db` instead of `mysql_select_db` - note the swap of the `s` and `y` in `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$connect = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass);
           mysql_select_db('database', $connect);
```

That's how you connect to a database.

You also spelled mysql wrong.

`Getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function msyql_select_db() with mysql_connect('localhost', 'name', 'pass'); <<msyql>>_select_db('dbname');`

Arrows around the error.

Answer (score 0):

you spelled your function incorrectly mysql not msyql

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question, but maybe this will help.

```
$session = mysql_connect('host','username','password');

mysql_select_db('database', $session);

$resultset = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM TABLE', $session);

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset);
```

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

May want to change localhost to '127.0.0.1' as well...I've had issues with that before.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  DEFINE ('DB_USER', '');     //specify the DB username like root.
  DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', ''); //specify the DB password.
  DEFINE ('DB_HOST', '');     //specify the DB hostname(localhost of IP address).
  DEFINE ('DB_NAME', '');    //specify the DB Name on which your doing operations.

  $dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .mysqli_connect_error() );

  $query="Specify your operation in a query format";

  @mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
  @mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend suppressing any errors that may arise when trying to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result= mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT username FROM users');  

while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {  
    $somethings[] .= $row['something'];  
}  
?>
```

Try this