# Recieving an error even though the script functions

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

I am receiving the following errors

> Warning: mysql_query()
>   [function.mysql-query]: Access denied
>   for user 'anticub1'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)
>
> Warning: mysql_query()
>   [function.mysql-query]: A link to the
>   server could not be established

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

When I submit the form everything goes into the database so I am not sure why I am getting that error...

```
<?php
$submit=$_POST['submit'];
$text=$_POST['text'];

if ($submit) {
  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","anticub1_shout","root12")
    or die("could not connect");
  mysql_select_db("anticub1_shoutbox") or die("could not find the db");

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('','$text')");}

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $post = $row["posts"];
    echo "$post"."<br>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Check the DB is on same server and username, password are correct

Comment: yes everything is correct when I submit the form information I am seeing it in the database

Comment: Please try to format your code more cleanly/consistently. It makes it really hard to read when your indentation isn't lined up and you don't stick to a particular brace style. Also, is there more of the code? Your `if` block isn't closed, so perhaps something after it is generating the error. And there are quite a few other problems with the code, such as the use of unsanitized user inputs directly in a query string. The echo line could also be simplified as `echo "$post<br>";`.

Comment: @Lèse majesté, actually the `if` block _is_ closed... look at the end of the `mysql_query` line, there's a `}`. Took me a moment to figure it out.

Comment: @Andew: Ah, I see it now. That's why formatting is important for readability.

Answer (score 0):

The warning:

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'anticub1'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Is **NOT** produced by your example script! because you provide a password there and its an other username.

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","anticub1_shout","root12")
```

Conclusion: You are searching at the wrong place. Search trough all your code for `mysql_connect("localhost","anticub1")`

Comment: I figured out the problem I took the connect out of the 'if' statement