# Warning: mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

Encountered with the following warning when trying to access the page:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/designand/www/www/random.php on line 13
```

Everything was working fine when I was testing it on XAMPP.

```
<?php
$db_hostname = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_name = "links";
$db_pass = "xxx";


$dbh = mysql_connect ($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_pass) or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

$num_displayed = 1 ;
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM 'links' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $num_displayed"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 

{
    echo "<a href=\"" . $row["link"] . "\"><img src=\"" . $row["image"] . "\" border=0 alt=\"\"></a>" ;
}
mysql_close($dbh);
?>
```

Comment: what differences are there between your setup on XAMPP and your setup on the server?

Comment: Please print the query that is genereated.

Comment: Try to `echo` **exact** query which you're trying to perform.

Comment: @zerkms sorry, it got pasted very ugly. added below :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An error like that almost always means there's a problem with your query.

To find out what error message MySQL returns, you can put `or die(mysql_error())` just before the semicolon after your `mysql_query` call. You may also want to print the exact query text you send to MySQL, as this may help you to see the actual problem.

Given that I don't know how much you may have anonymized this example, I can't be sure if this is the actual error, but it looks like you've surrounded your table name with apostrophes (`'`). This is incorrect; the correct character for escaping table and column names is `` ` ``.

Comment: Also it is possible that `$num_displayed` is not defined.

Comment: You are correct. Apostrophes (') were killing it. (`) fixed it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

"supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource" means that the query didn't return a valid resource. It failed. To view the error just print out mysql_error() after mysql_query().

Could be that the table doesn't exist. Did you check it?

The second thinkg - ORDER BY RAND() is bad! You should think of different ways on how to shuffle the result. Just google it, there are a lot of other ways to do it - [ORDER BY RAND() @ Google](http://www.google.lv/search?q=ORDER+BY+RAND)

Comment: "The second thinkg - ORDER BY RAND() is bad!" --- he is **newbie**. He cannot even perform simplest query, and you're trying to teach him about performant randomizing :-S "that the table" --- that "table" doesn't exist, since table cannot be specified with single quotes around.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM 'links' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $num_displayed");
```

To:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM 'links' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $num_displayed") or die (echo mysql_error());
```

It seems like the SQL is failing to return a valid response. Adding the above should show you the last MySQL error and help point you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code to get if the mysql is throwing any errors:

```
  $result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

while(....
```