# Linking PHP with mySQL problem

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home2/wizardso/public_html/tab1_content.php on line 6
```

this is the error that i am getting when i uploaded my db-driven webpage to my web-hosting. The same webpage was running smoothly on my localhost/ server. But its not working over the internet. **Please HELP.**

**UPDATE**

These are the contents of my file tab1_content.php

```
<?php
$query="select * from subcatagory where catagory_id='c001'";
$res=mysql_query($query,$con);
$query_cat="select * from catagory where catagory_id='c001'";
$res_cat=mysql_query($query_cat,$con);
$current_cat=mysql_fetch_assoc($res_cat);
?>
```

Comment: Show us your code and look at MySQL errors!

Comment: Sounds like you aren't connecting to the MySQL server / database correctly.

Comment: I have uploaded the php code and the database correctly. the connectivity is also okay. thanks for the downvote instead. i didnt expect such behaviour from people like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error most likely results from the fact that there is something wrong with the mysql_query ("result resource") that you are calling mysql_fetch_assoc() on. Try running just the query and see what errors are returned.

All the error you posted tells you is that something went wrong with the query, it could be anything from a MySQL database connection problem to a typo in your script. Please show us your code so we can see what exactly is causing the error.

`echo mysql_error();`

**Edit**

Your code appears to look OK- are you sure that there is table within your database called "catagory" (then again- are you sure it's not "category"?), and that within that database is a record with a `catagory_id` of "c001"?

To test this, try echoing `mysql_affected_rows();` , this gives the number of rows "affected" by the last query. If you get `0`, then that means that there is no such record.

Comment: @Coding-Freak Your question was voted down by someone probably because you didn't post any code or evidence of what had caused the error, so it's very difficult for us to help you.

Comment: but you people could have given me a chance atleast before voting me down. I am a newbie to this website.

Comment: @Coding-Freak - You have no idea who downvoted you.

Comment: i updated the question. check it out.

Comment: As you can see, someone has just upvoted your question, you're back to 0. Like Jared said, anyone can upvote/downvote questions. Welcome to the SO community! Now please post some code so we can fix your problem. :)

Comment: @Coding Bad questions are downvoted, as simple as that. If you improve the question, the downvote may be removed. No need to keep complaining.

Comment: @all - check the question. i have updated it with the code.

Comment: @anonymous:- thanks for downvoting and upvoting back. you people are really interesting. :)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever result set you're passing to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is invalid because the query with `mysql_query()` did not complete.  Check the mysql error with `mysql_error()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Check your Database connectivity settings i hope that it may be one of the reason for the empty result set.
```

Thanks