# mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/virtua15/public_html/main/1515/dafreg.php on line 9

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858304/mysql-fetch-assoc-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource-in-p)
>   [mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646427/mysql-fetch-assoc-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource)

Im working with two MYSQL databases trying to gahter data from both of them to insert in to field for submission to another database. When i go and use the mysql_fetch_assoc() for the query it gives me an error. I did some research and I cannot find anything that really pertaied to my issue. I was wondering if i could get some help.

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","***********","*********") or die ("Couldn't Connect"); //host,username,password
mysql_select_db("virtua15_jo151") or die ("Could not find database");


$query = mysql_query("SELECT jos_comprofiler.firstname, jos_comprofiler.lastname, jos_users.username, jos_comprofiler.cb_country, jos_users.email FROM jos_users LEFT JOIN jos_comprofiler ON jos_users.id=jos_comprofiler.id WHERE jos_users.id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($id));


if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $firstname = $row['firstname']; //This is whatever the field is called in your table
    $lastname = $row['lastname'];
    $loginname = $row['jos_users.username'];
    $country = $row['cb_country'];
    $email = $row['email'];

}

?>
```

below this is all HTML I can include that if need be,

Comment: Your sql is wrong. Now this mistake can be anything.... You have to check table name, column name thoroughly. I advice you, in phpmyadmin, write just an initial portion of the query, see if it runs or not.... Then add 1 joint statement, if it runs, join another. In this way, you can spot the error even if you don't have clue where the error is at 1st.

Comment: Please, stop writing new code with `mysql_*`, and learn to use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: Whats that supposed to mean? Why can't I write my code how I want. Secondly I would like to know why I lost 4 reputation points because of this post. I'm here to ask questions on how to do things in regards to PHP and other things. I don't appreciate being penalized for asking questions that I don't know the answer to AFTER I did my research both here and on the internet and claimed that I did so in my posting.

Comment: It's not about "not writing the code you want". It's about asking question for some of your code: (1) your SQL is wrong (2) your code is ugly (`or die` my god, my god!!) (3) if you ask a question with bad SQL, with ugly code, and without trying to understand good suggestions (**PDO is the right and safe way to go**) then sorry we won't help you.

Comment: Please another suggestion: check for samples of mysql_xx: `while(list($firstname, $lastname, $loginname, $country, $email)=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {}` is easier to both read and maintain.

Comment: David, [Google has nearly 7 million results for that error message](https://www.google.com/search?ix=seb&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=mysql_fetch_assoc()%3A+supplied+argument+is+not+a+valid+MySQL+result+resource). [StackOverflow has 5,000+](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_fetch_assoc%28%29%3A+supplied+argument+is+not+a+valid+MySQL+result+resource). There's no way you researched this issue before posting as the entire Related column are duplicates as well.. Stackoverflow pointed this out when you entered that title...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something  is  wrong with query check with  `print mysql_error();`

Check query. quote properly values assigned in query.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT jos_comprofiler.firstname, jos_comprofiler.lastname,
         jos_users.username, jos_comprofiler.cb_country, jos_users.email 
         FROM jos_users LEFT JOIN jos_comprofiler ON jos_users.id=jos_comprofiler.id 
         WHERE jos_users.id ='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'");
```

Comment: `mysql_query` always returns a `resource`, even if no results were found. If it returns `false`, it means there was an error in the query. In that case, `mysql_num_rows` will complain about exactly the same thing.

Comment: Agree. Updated my answer