# mysql_affected_rows() in php

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

I have next class:

```
<?php
    class DbHelper{
        private $databaseURL;
        private $databaseUName;
        private $databasePWord;
        private $databaseName;
        private $nameOfDbWithWorkers;
        private $connection;

        function __construct($dbURL, $dbUserName, $dbPword, $dbName, $nameOfDbWithWorkers){
            $this->databaseURL = $dbURL;
            $this->databaseUName = $dbUserName;
            $this->databasePWord = $dbPword;
            $this->databaseName = $dbName;
            $this->nameOfDbWithWorkers = $nameOfDbWithWorkers;
        }

        function setConnectionToDb(){
            $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->databaseURL,$this->databaseUName,$this->databasePWord) OR DIE("can't connect to DB"); 
            mysql_select_db($this->databaseName, $this->connection)or die ("Error while connecting to database");
        }

        function getUser($login, $pass){
            echo "$login, $pass";
            $query = "SELECT type FROM $this->nameOfDbWithWorkers WHERE login = '$login' and password = '$pass';"; 
            $queryResult = $this->getDataFromDbByQuery($query);
            if ((mysql_affected_rows($this->connection) == 1)){
                $meta = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult);
                if ($meta['type']=='admin'){
                    return 'admin';
                }
                if ($meta['type']=='user'){
                    return 'user';
                }
                else{
                    return 'nomatch';
                }
            }
            else{               
                 return 'nomatch';
            }           
        }

        function getDataFromDbByQuery($query){
            $this->setConnectionToDb();
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            mysql_close($this->connection);
            return $result;
        }
}
?>
```

and invoke this by

```
$dbHelp = new DbHelper($dbURL, $dbUName, $dbPword, $dbName, $nameOfDbWithWorkers);
$userType = $dbHelp->getUser($login, $pass);
```

And have a next error:

```
Warning: mysql_affected_rows(): 5 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in Z:\home\ecl.ru\www\classes\dbhelper.php on line 27
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't open and close the database connection for each query to execute. You can execute `mysql_close()` at the end of your script instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first , use mysql_num_rows for row count , mysql_affected_rows returns number of changed rows , as is written in manual on php.net

> Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query associated with link_identifier.

second - evry time you are using mysql function , put there link identifier or result identifier

Comment: "second" is not required. It will use the last opened then.

Comment: i know , but it is good practice - i know lot of people not doing this and doing two listings ( which produce an error )

Comment: Its cleaner, you are right, but especially when using multiple connections, I would suggest using `PDO` or `MySQLi` anyway ([/offtopic] ;)).

Comment: Yes, it is better, but it is offtopic now :-)

Answer (score 9):

You shutdown the connection

```
    function getDataFromDbByQuery($query){
        $this->setConnectionToDb();
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        mysql_close($this->connection); // <----
        return $result;
    }
```

If you want to use it later in your script you shouldn't do this ;) However, because PHP closes all open itself at the scripts end you don't need to close it yourself at all.

Update (Just to avoid the next question ;))

You probably want to use `mysql_num_rows()` instead of `mysql_affected_rows()`. First one returns the number of rows returned by a `SELECT`-query, the other one returns the number of rows affected (;)) by a `DELETE`, `INSERT`, or `UPDATE` query. Oh, and `REPLACE` I forgot.

Comment: he uses mysql_affected_rows between connect and close

Comment: @SergeS no he's not, he's using it after closing the connection.

Comment: @SergeS: No. As you can see he call `getDataFromDbByQuery()` _before_ he calls `mysql_affected_rows()`

Comment: somehow i readed this badly ... sry

Comment: @KingCrunch to improve your answer, you should add an explanation regarding how it is useless to use `mysql_affected_rows()` for a `SELECT` query, because it will still not work after fixing the `mysql_close()` problem.

Comment: @Matthieu: Hehe, already did it ;)

Answer (score 2):

> mysql_affected_rows

Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE

and you are using SELECT..

For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

hope that solves your problem. you do need to change bit of code to handle this.

Comment: That is not the immediate problem of the OP, but will be after he fixes the `mysql_close()` problem.

Comment: Mattieu why not he will never get mysql_affected_rows($this->connection) == 1 using select statement .

Comment: I agree with you, I was pointing out that even if he did what you are suggesting, that wouldn't fix the problem he's having now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the signature for [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows):

> `int mysql_affected_rows ([ resource
>   $link_identifier ] )`
>
> Get the number of affected rows by the
>   last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE
>   query associated with link_identifier.
>
> `link_identifier` The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last
>   link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it
>   will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no
>   arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level
>   error is generated.

So it requires an open link to the DB. However, your `getDataFromDbByQuery()` method closes the connection before you call the function:

```
    function getDataFromDbByQuery($query){
        $this->setConnectionToDb();
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        mysql_close($this->connection);
        return $result;
    }
```