# mysql_fetch_array error - Not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am very new to PHP, trying to write a script which connects to a MySQL database and simply displays the contents in list format under each heading;

My table contains an ID (AutoIncrement), FName, SName & EAddress fields.

The database is called iphonehe_MGFSales and the username is iphonehe_MGFSale - I have added the user to the DB with full privileges.

I am trying to establish my connection to the DB using the mysql function with this code;

```
mysql_connect ("localhost", "iphonehe_MGFSale", "xxxxxxx") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("iphonehe_MGFSales");
```

The table I have created is called MGFSales DB. I am using this code to attempt to build the query;

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MGFSales_DB");
```

And finally I am trying to display the results using the following code;

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($query)) {
echo "<br /> ID: " .$row['ID']. "<br /> First Name: ".$row['FName']. "<br /> Last Name: ".$row['LName']. "<br /> Email: ".$row['EAddress']. "<br />";
}
```

I have named the file index.php and uploaded to my server, when running I get the following error 'Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/iphonehe/public_html/pauldmorris.co.uk/mgf/index.php on line 16'

Anyone point me in the right direction?  Line 16 of my code seems pretty tight from what I can see, am i overlooking something?
Thanks

Comment: Does the table you created contain any data?

Comment: Yes, I have entered two test entries into it

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL query problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800202/mysql-query-problem)

Comment: It was going to suggest the examples in the PHP manual page but most of them fail to do proper error checking :(

Comment: @Rasel - Table name is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because of null resource found in **$query**..
you need to check this like below code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MGFSales_DB"); or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ){
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($query)) {
echo "<br /> ID: " .$row['ID']. "<br /> First Name: ".$row['FName']. "<br /> Last Name: ".$row['LName']. "<br /> Email: ".$row['EAddress']. "<br />";
 }
}
```

OR you can also refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

Try this may help you.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message now changes to Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/iphonehe/public_html/pauldmorris.co.uk/mgf/index.php on line 16

Comment: Nice :) Thanks you lot :)

Answer (score 7):

The error is in `mysql_fetch_array` line only, correcting this should be first step in troubleshooting.

change `mysql_fetch_array` to

```
mysqli_fetch_array
```

becuase the latest updates in mysql or php does not accept mysql but accepts only mysqli. Also change everywhere mysql to mysqli in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` returns **false** when it fails, which will produce the error you're getting during `mysql_fetch_array`.

Please add some error checking to your code, and print out/log the error messages - can't help any more than that without knowing what the source error is.

Comment: Ok, thanks Mat. I guess I will now go and learn about error logging and how to do it ha

Answer (score 1):

Check the return code on `mysql_select_db`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not apply mysql_fetch_array directly..

you should first check for data ..

```
if(mysql_num_row($query)>0){
   your code   
}
else{
   echo 'it brings no data....';
}
```

it checks if there is no data then it will execute else block other wise you will have smooth execution ...

Comment: Altering my code to incorporate the above changes the error message to Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_num_row() in /home/iphonehe/public_html/pauldmorris.co.uk/mgf/index.php on line 16