# Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

This is the part of my script that I'm having issues with. All of the following queries work and the results display properly on the [page](http://septimuscomputers.co.cc/ProductIndex.php?sort=lowHigh) except for $sType="rating". This the one that causes the warning to appear in place of the data. I've tried running the specific query on the server and it returns properly. It only gives me an error when I use it on the webpage. Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

```
$sType=$_GET["sort"];
$newQuery;
    if($sType=="lowHigh")
    {
        $newQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY SalePrice");
    }
    else if($sType=="highLow")
    {
        $newQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY SalePrice DESC");  
    }
    else if($sTpye=="rating")
    {
        $newQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY Rating DESC, NumRatings DESC") or die(mysql_error());

    }
    else if($sType=="mostReviews")
    {
        $newQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY NumRatings DESC");     
    }
        $p1=mysql_fetch_array($newQuery);
        $p2=mysql_fetch_array($newQuery);
        $p3=mysql_fetch_array($newQuery);
        $p4=mysql_fetch_array($newQuery);
        $p5=mysql_fetch_array($newQuery);
        $p6=mysql_fetch_array($newQuery);
        $p7=mysql_fetch_array($newQuery);
        $p8=mysql_fetch_array($newQuery);
```

Comment: Is the spelling error really there? `$sTpye=="rating"` or just a copy-paste accident?

Comment: Consider using a `switch` statement instead of all those `if .. elseif` blocks. It'll be more readable

Comment: Doesn't a switch only use numeric values as cases?

Comment: @DangerousDave No, you can use any data type supporting equality comparison

Comment: turning on error reporting in your php configuration would have made this error instantly detectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mistyped $`sType` in your check for "rating".

Comment: Ha! thanks a lot! I must have lost it in all the different text colors. Thanks for being that set of fresh eyes.