# Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

I'm having a problem with this mysql code. I presume its a basic error in the $sqlx... line but I'm slightly lost.

The code basically prints messages from a db
Here is the code:

```
$sqls="SELECT username FROM social WHERE `adder`='$username'";
$results=mysql_query($sqls);
$resulti= mysql_num_rows($results);
if ($resulti==0) {
echo "You haven't added anyone yet. Find some <a   href=\"/social/suggestions\">suggestions</a>";
}
$row=mysql_fetch_array($results);

$sqlx="SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `sender` IN ($row)";
$resultx= mysql_query($sqlx); 
$resultz= mysql_num_rows($resultx);
if ($resultz==0){
echo "No messages at all!!";
}
else {
$finished="false";
$r=0;
While(($rowx=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultx))&&($finished=="false")) {
//echo off messages
```

$username is got further up the file.

Here is the error:

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/user/public_html/social/iframe/index.php on line 34

Line 34 is `$resultz= mysql_num_rows($resultx);`
But like i said the error is probably the line two up from that.

One interesting happens. "No messages at all!!" is echoed out which means the result of the `mysql_query` is 0. This is why I am convinced it is the line 32, (`$sqlx`)

Any idea??

Have I done the `mysql_fetch_array` wrong when getting `$row`??
thanks

Comment: `$results=mysql_query($sqls) or die('Error: '. mysql_error());`. Also, use PDO instead of mysql_* functions, they're obsolete now.

Comment: @N.B., although I agree that PDO would be a better option for new projects, I disagree that `mysql_*()` are obsolete. Officially they are **not obsolete**, it is just a subjective opinion.

Comment: @binaryLV - that's just a matter of semantics, they are obsolete. I assume you've used PDO and mysqli so I won't get into the huge discussion saying things that you already know. People should start avoiding mysql_* functions, not only due to security reasons but for the sake of learning how to code in a way that's efficient and easier to read when other people get involved in their code.

Comment: I think it would be better for him to focus on writing better looking and more readable code overall than switching to PDO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($results);

$sqlx="SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `sender` IN ($row)";
```

This will create the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `sender` IN (Array)
```

This is obviously not a valid MySQL query. You have to process the array.

```
$sqlx = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `sender` IN ("; // start of query

foreach($row as $r)
    $sqlx .= "'".$r['username']."',"; // insert all returned usernames

$sqlx = substr($sqlx,0,-1).')'; // substract the last comma and close the query
```

Or, as RiaD pointed out in the comments:

```
$sqlx = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `sender` IN (".
        implode(',',array_map(function($x){return "'".$x['username']."'"; }, $row)).
        ")";
```

PS: Riad, it should be `$x['username']` instead of `$x` and you forgot the semicolon ;)

Comment: implode(',',array_map(function($x){return "'".$x."'"}, $row)); is more readable:)

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_query($sqlx)` return false instead of result. It means any error occured. Try to check is `$sqlx` correct query and check mysql_error() to get what error is occured. To check was here any error or not you can use

```
if(!$resultx){
     print 'error:'.mysql_error();
}
else{
    //use result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query fails `mysql_query($sqlx)` returns `false` rather than `resource`. So, you need to check, that this function returned true (e.g. `if (!results) {}`) nad print use `mysql_error()` to see what error was.

```
if(!$resultx){
   print 'error:'.mysql_error();
}
```

Also, you are embedding `$row` variable into the query string. But this var is an `Array`, so you end up with a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `sender` IN (Array)
```

See [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) manual for details