# mysql errors in site log file

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

When I checked my site log error file I found this error:

> Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in /home/mysite/public_html/include/config.php on line
>   17

The line 17 is:

```
$rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

And, this line is inside a function:

```
function get_val($val,$table,$where,$return){
    $query=mysql_query("select $val from $table $where");
    $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    return $rows[''.$return.''];
    mysql_free_result($query);
}
```

There is no error in the browser but in the log_file error I find this message.

Comment: print the query and see is it ok or not

Comment: I suspect one of your input values is invalid or blank and hence the query is not valid. btw I would strongly advise you to rethink your design. Without seeing the rest of your code, a function like this easily risks leading to bad separation in your code. If you had a field called 'price' that you later wanted to change to 'cost' you could have real problems just identifying where you need to make that change.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether a resource is `null` or not.

```
function get_val($val,$table,$where,$return){
    $query=mysql_query("select $val from $table $where");
    if($query)
     {
        $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        mysql_free_result($query);
        return $rows[$return];
     }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may also put @ instead of checking $query for null:

```
$query = mysql_query(...);
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: -1 Suppressing errors in not advised here. He's building a query dynamically and should really be capturing any errors his script is throwing.