# Getting "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource" when calling mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting the same mysql error code but I dont know how to correct it.

Error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/we/ez/y_/weezy.co.uk/public_html/search.php on line 29
```

I have marked out line 29 on the code below.

What does this mean?

Thanks

```
<?php
// Change the fields below as per the requirements
$db_host="";
$db_username="";
$db_password="";
$db_name="";
$db_tb_name="data";
$db_tb_atr_name="name";
$db_tb_atr_name="email";
$db_tb_atr_name="location";


//Now we are going to write a script that will do search task
// leave the below fields as it is except while loop, which will display results on screen

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$query_for_result=mysql_query("

SELECT name, email, location

FROM data WHERE 

$db_tb_atr_name like '%".$query."%'");
echo "<h2>Search Results</h2><ol>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< LINE 29 
{
echo "<li>";
echo substr($row["name"], $row["email"], $row["location"]);
echo "</li><hr/>";
}
echo "</ol>";

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: check if the request successfull: `if ($query_for_result) {` `}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

Answer (score 6):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Where have you set `$result` to anything?

You probably meant

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
```

Answer (score 1):

you store the result of your query in a variable named `$query_for_result`, later on you try to read `$result`, which is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the result of `mysql_query` to `$query_for_result` but then trying to loop over `$result` in `mysql_fetch_array()`. Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("...");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  ...
```

OR

```
$query_for_result = mysql_query("...");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result)) {
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this but now nothing shows, not an error message or a search result, what do I do next?

Answer (score 0):

You should also check if there are any rows returned

```
$rs = mysql_query("
  SELECT name, email, location
    FROM data 
   WHERE ".$db_tb_atr_name." like '%".$query."%'
");

if(mysql_num_rows($rs)){

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    // code
  }
} else {
// no results
}
```