# mysql_fetch_assoc very strange

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

okay so here is my code.

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';


$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);


$image = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($image);
$imagearray = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$realimage = $imagearray['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $realimage;

?>
```

the page uses GET to get the id but then it gives me this error:

`Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a6289454/public_html/get.php on line 9`

Comment: Maybe it is because your query return no result/record

Comment: @MuhammadAbrar Even an empty table returns a valid resource from `mysql_query` (it will cause `mysql_fetch_assoc` to return false). The error is likely on the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var_dump(mysql_error());` will help you find the error message. But most likely thing is you need quotes:

```
$image = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `id`='".$id."'";
```

Comment: I also suggest to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) instead of `addslashes`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in addslashes(), try mysql_real_escape_string() instead.

Comment: nope im still getting mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a6289454/public_html/get.php on line 9

Comment: No reason to escape an integer..

Comment: Sure, no reason to escape it if it's an integer but you never know what it might be since it comes from the GET.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding slashes to `$_REQUEST['id']`? It should be an integer

Try this code:

```
if(is_numeric($_REQUEST['id'])){

    $q = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = " . $id; // Don't put variables in strings!
    $rs= mysql_query($q) or die("There is an error in the query:<br>" . $q . "<br><br>The error is: ". mysql_error()); // Throw and error if there is one.
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

} else { die('Not a valid ID'); }
```

Also for good practice use `require_once('connect.php');` rather than `include 'connect.php';`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $image = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=$id";
 $result = mysql_query($image) or die(mysql_error());
```

Try that

Also for your $id use type casting it's a simple solution to a simple problem

```
 $id = (int) $_REQUEST['id'];
```