# supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource

Tags: php, mysql, function, warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

I am getting this error while trying to run a function. I am sending a value `$id` to this function and trying to return the associated array. But I get a warning `supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource`.

But if i run the same code by eliminating the function part and give a static value to `$id` it returns the result correctly. This is the function

```
<?php
    mysql_select_db($database_spyware, $spyware);
    function get_product($id)
    {
        $query = sprintf("select product.descr as product_descr, product_id as Product_id,
                          category.descr as category from sp_url
                          inner join product
                          on product.id = sp_url.product_id
                          inner join category
                          on product.category_id = category.id
                          where sp_url.id = $id");

        $query_result = mysql_query($query, $spyware) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_rs_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result);
        $totalRows_rs = mysql_num_rows($query_result);
        return($row_rs_query);
    }
?>
```

Comment: What value has `$id` been assigned when you feed it to the function?

Comment: its an integer value taken from a file !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because your second parameter spyware in function "mysql_query" is declared outside the function and is unreadable on your function scope.

try

global $spyware;

at the beginning of the function.

or leave the second parameter empty.

Comment: Alternatively to avoid using a global, you could feed `$spyware` to your function as the second parameter.  Ex. `function get_product($id, $spyware)`.