# PHP Login Script result resource

Tags: php, mysql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

When typing in a username and password im getting the error

mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

IT IS SAYING I HAVE NO DATABASE SELECTED ...

I was wondering what this error means. Could it be a problem connecting to the database or is it a syntax problem. here is the code for the username and password

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '$user'");
                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                if($numrows == 1){
                    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                    $dbid = $row['id'];
                    $dbuser = $row['username'];
                    $dbpass = $row['password'];
                    $dbactive = $row['active'];

                    if($password == $dbpass){
                        if($dbactive == 1){

                            //set session info
                            $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;

                            echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b> Click here to go to member page.";

                        }else
                            echo "You must activate your account to login.";

                    }else 
                        echo "You did not enter the correct password.";


                }else 
                    echo "The username you entered was not found.";
            }


        }else
            echo "You must enter your username.";

    }
```

The problem is in the $query line. the first line

Comment: `var_dump("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '$user'");` + `mysql_error();`

Comment: Your query has failed. do `$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` to find out why.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that your not connected or not selecting the correct database, you should use `mysql_error()` to track this down. **But** I also see some logic confusion, here is an example of a super simple login, checks should be made on the database query, not by PHP (plus there is no need to store the password anywhere other then in the database). You should also hash user account passwords & escape user input, hope it helps..

```
<?php 
session_start();
$db = mysql_connect('host','uesr','pass') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('database') or die(mysql_error());

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `username`,`active`
                          FROM Users 
                          WHERE username ='$user' && password='$password' && active=1
                          LIMIT 1");

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1){
        //Log in user found
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        $_SESSION['username']  = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['active']    = $row['active'];
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] =true;
        header('Location: ./members.php');
        die;
    }else{
        //failed login
        $_SESSION['logged_in']=false;
        $_SESSION['log_in_error']='Fail!! Account not active or incorrect login information!';
        header('Location: ./login.php');
        die;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried your code and I got the same error

Comment: what is the name of your database? NOT table, perhaps rename the database to something other then a table within it. then you wont get confused.

Comment: Also are you using `mysql_select_db('database') or die(mysql_error());
` I notice @Terry Seidler answer does not include this.

Answer (score 0):

Like zerkms suggested, try printing the mysql_error() to screen.
Something like:

```
$query = mysql_query("your_query here");
if(!$query){
    echo 'Error! : ' . mysql_error();
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Before you do all of this, make sure you are connected to a database. For example:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'database_user', 'database_password');
if(!$link){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//select your db
mysql_select_db("YOUR_DB_NAME",$link);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '$user'");
if(!$result){
    echo 'Error! ' . mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: I did what you said and the echo said that i have no database selected.

Comment: Have you connected to a database?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Yea i have in another script it look like this  mysql_connect("hostname","username","password");
mysql_select_db("Users");

Comment: Then in the other script i write require(connect.php)

Comment: And the mysql_connect works? I have edited my first post with some more mysql_connect 'debugging'.

Comment: it the database called `Users`? dont confuse that with the table.

Comment: Good point by Lawrence ;)
Just like with mysql_query and mysql_connect, you can also verify the result of mysql_select_db(). It returns TRUE on success and FALSE when it fails.

Comment: I did the test and i successfully connected to the database that is not the problem i guess any other ideas?

Comment: Check my answer to compare it with your code. ;)

Comment: Nevermind i changed it and still got the errors. that isn't the problem

Comment: I am still having this same problem does anyone have any ideas?????