# Error handling for a mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, function

My question is how to remove the error, message saying

`mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result.`

I need to throw/catch this error, but not sure how to do this.

When this function has a result to return, it works properly.

It is just that when when the result returns null, it says supplied argument is not a valid mysql result.

So how do I remove this error, so when it doesn't have anything to return, instead of displaying `mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result`, it shows the user what I want.

```
$posts = show_allgroupsposts1($myusers,5);
if (count($posts)){
do a bunch of stuff.
}else{
nothing to display.
}
?>
```

**currently, it returns:**

```
mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result
nothing to display.
```

Comment: The mysql query you perform is incorrect. And we cannot diagnose more until you show it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check wither the result variable is false.

```
if($result)
    mysql_fetch_object();
else
    ...do nothing
```

Comment: ... or he could fix his broken query instead

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure that it never reaches the statement if the result is invalid:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error");
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
```

Comment: `or die("Error")` should never be used in production

Comment: is this better than the previous answer?

Comment: @arboles: neither are good enough - you just need to fix your query

Comment: I agree. However you do it, getting false in your fetch result is a sign that you need to fix something, most likely your query.