# Two WHERE statements

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

I've done a search and couldn't find anything that could specifically help me.

I was hoping you could help.

I'd like to execute a MySQL query which searches a table for entries which meet two criteria (type = green AND on = yes)

I am presented with: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /link/to/my/file.php on line 36

Here is an extract from the code (line 36):

```
`$green = "SELECT * FROM homepage_vars WHERE type = 'green' AND on = 'yes'";
 $green = mysql_query($green);
 $green = mysql_fetch_array($green);`
```

Comment: after running mysql_query($green) try printing mysql_error($green).  That will help you figure out what is wrong.  Also, making $green equal to three different things will probably cause you confusion in the long run.

Answer (score 7):

`ON` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).  If you use it as a column or table identifier, you need to enclose it in backquotes:

```
SELECT * FROM homepage_vars WHERE type = 'green' AND `on` = 'yes'
```

You'll then have another problem once the query syntax is corrected.  You have overwritten the variable `$green` several times. Originally, it held your query SQL, but was then used for the query result resource.  That's fine, but then you will overwrite it with the row fetched by `mysql_fetch_array()` and its contents will be an array or `FALSE`.  Subsequent attempts to fetch rows will fail since `$green` is no longer a result resource.

Always test for query success or failure before attempting to fetch rows.  Call `mysql_error()` to see the error reported by the MySQL server, which would have pointed to *invalid syntax near 'on* or something similar.

```
$green = "SELECT * FROM homepage_vars WHERE type = 'green' AND on = 'yes'"; 
$query = mysql_query($green); 
if ($query) {
  // Don't overwrite your query resource!
  // Use a new variable!
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
}
else {
  // Failure!
  echo mysql_error();
}
```