# Error when storing multiple records in JSON format

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've problem with my code, the reason, when run query un PHP FILE, this retrieve all records from `SELECT * FROM material`, then it pass to JS FILE for process and store all records in an array json format, but display this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result 
resource in C:\AppServ\www\biblioteca\include\doLogin.php on line 31 []
```

_

**PHP FILE WITH FUNCTIONS**

```
.........
public function searchMat($tipoBusqueda,$terminoBuscar){

$query = " SELECT * FROM material ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$resultArray =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
return $resultArray;
}
```

**OTHER PHP FILE with functions**

```
$results = $db->searchMat($tipoBusqueda, $terminoBuscar);
$jsonSearchResults = array();

if ($results != false) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $jsonSearchResults = array (
        'clavemat' => $row['cve_mat'],
        'tipomat' => $row['tipo_mat'],
        'titulomat' => $row['titulo_mat'],
        'autormat' => $row['autor_mat'],
        'editmat' => $row['edit_mat'],
        'success' => 'success', 
        );  
    }

    echo json_encode($jsonSearchResults);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Comment: Your JS FILE should be a PHP file.

Comment: The error message says the `$result` is not a valid parameter. Could you please give us the code that generates it, i.e. the source of `$db->searchMat`?

Comment: Also your `$jsonSearchResults` variable gets overwritten every time. You need to push records to it instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) two times. The first time on the [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) you got from [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), the second time on an array - invalid.

Also, when you would loop over all rows, you need to [add to](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) `$jsonSearchResults`. As @RezaSanaie already said, it gets overwritten each iteration in your code. It should be:

```
public function searchMat() {
/* returns the material table as a resource */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM material";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    return $result;
}

$results = $db->searchMat();
$jsonSearchResults = array();
while ($results!=false && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    array_push($jsonSearchResults, array(
        'clavemat' => $row['cve_mat'],
        'tipomat' => $row['tipo_mat'],
        'titulomat' => $row['titulo_mat'],
        'autormat' => $row['autor_mat'],
        'editmat' => $row['edit_mat'],
        'success' => 'success'
    ));
}   
echo json_encode($jsonSearchResults);
```

Comment: I try ur code, but save only first record from database and I Want store all records from query!

Comment: You need to tell us in the question what you want to approach ;-) Then you have even two errors... Editing answer.

Comment: Ur code its OK, but no print json formar, only print in HTML format: [{"clavemat":"LICOELMCUS","tipomat":"Libro","titulomat":"Contabilidad","autormat":"Elias Flores","editmat":"McGraw Hill","success":"success"},{"clavemat":"LICUDEMCNU","tipomat":"Libro","titulomat":"Curso java","autormat":"Deitel","editmat":"McGraw Hill","success":"success"}] and in Firebug dont see Json format!

Comment: Huh? That is JSON, isn't it? If you want to receive it as JSON, you will need to set an appropriate mime time.

Comment: Im sorry man, ur code its Ok, just left this line "header('Content-Type: application/json');" before "echo json_encode($jsonSearchResults)", Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your searchmat function should return $result not the first row.

Answer (score 2):

in this line:

```
$results = $db->searchMat($tipoBusqueda, $terminoBuscar);
```

`$results` is an array, not a MySQL Result Resource. So you don't need to pass it into `mysql_fetch_assoc`. You have already done that in `searchMat`.

There is a problem here though. `searchMat` only gets one row from the result and returns it. After that, you no longer have any way to get the rest of the rows. You should either have `searchMat` return the resource or move your `while` loop into `searchMat` so that it can return an array containing all results from the query.

Try it like this:

```
public function searchMat($tipoBusqueda,$terminoBuscar){
    $query = "
        SELECT 
            cve_mat AS clavemat,
            tipo_mat AS tipomat,
            titulo_mat AS titulomat,
            autor_mat AS autormat,
            edit_mat AS editmat,
            success
        FROM material
    ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    $out = array();
    while ($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $out[] = $row;
    }
    return $out;
}


$results = $db->searchMat($tipoBusqueda, $terminoBuscar);

if (!empty($results)) {
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

I've also changed your query so that columns are already named as you want them. Then you don't have to go to the trouble of copying one array into another.

Comment: Rithg, I move while to SearchMat function and I print  echo json_encode($jsonSearchResults); but the problem is: The content from json format no isn't in json format if not there is in HTML format like this: [{"clavemat":"LICOELMCUS","tipomat":"Libro","titulomat":"Contabilidad","autormat":"Elias Flores","editmat":"McGraw Hill","success":"success"},{"clavemat":"LICUDEMCNU","tipomat":"Libro","titulomat":"Curso java","autormat":"Deitel","editmat":"McGraw Hill","success":"success"}]

Comment: Your issue has nothing whatsoever to do with JSON. I've posted some code as an example of how you could do this. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks man, ur code its Ok, just left this line "header('Content-Type: application/json');" before "echo json_encode($jsonSearchResults)"... but @Bergi answerme first!