# what's wrong on my sql query?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

```
<?
 $result ="select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.*, b.name as brandname ,(case when max(length(d.pcode)) >0  then 1  else 0 end) as eventflag,  min(d.price) as eventprice 
from brand b , product a left join event_product d on a.pcode = d.pcode where a.status != 0 and a.hotflag = 0 and a.bcode = b.code and  a.bcode = '$bcode'
group by a.pcode, a.bcode, a.ocode, a.ccode, a.pname, a.copy, a.etc, a.company, a.origin, a.status, a.opt1name, a.opt1value, a.opt2name, a.opt2value, a.opt3name, a.opt3value, a.gift_name, a.gift_file, a.gift_s_file, a.saleprice, a.saleflag, a.hotflag, a.hotcode, a.hotprice, a.price, a.term, a.point, a.pointflag, a.pointorder, a.content, a.html_check, a.couple1, a.couple2, a.couple3, a.regdate, a.cnt, a.sort, a.delflag, b.name   
order by a.regdate desc limit 12"; 

  $row_object = mysql_query("Select Found_Rows() as rowcount");
  $row_object = mysql_fetch_object($row_object);
  $actual_row_count = $row_object->rowcount;

?>

 SOME HTML 

 <? while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

 HTML OUTPUT

 <? } ?>
```

That shows.. Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource near

```
 <? while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
```

MYSQL VERSION is 5.2.3-falcon-alpha.

Comment: You are not doing any error checking in your query. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: `mysql_error()` is your friend

Comment: #1.  mysql_* extensions are deprecated use `mysqli` or `PDO`....  
#2.  When I have a query that just won't work, I echo out the query itself -- then copy it into phpmyadmin and see what it has to tell me....  I often find my answer that way...  but both the guys above are correct in that you really need to do some error checking.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a string to `mysql_fetch_array` instead of MySQL resource.
You need to do:

```
$res = mysql_query($result);
```

before

```
<? while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
```

Then, if the `$result` query is correct, you should get results.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing `mysql_fetch_array($result)`, but `$result` actually contains the *text* of your query:

```
$result ="select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.*, b.name as brandname ,(case when max(length(d.pcode)) >0  then 1  else 0 end) as eventflag,  min(d.price) as eventprice 
from brand b , product a left join event_product d on a.pcode = d.pcode where a.status != 0 and a.hotflag = 0 and a.bcode = b.code and  a.bcode = '$bcode'
group by a.pcode, a.bcode, a.ocode, a.ccode, a.pname, a.copy, a.etc, a.company, a.origin, a.status, a.opt1name, a.opt1value, a.opt2name, a.opt2value, a.opt3name, a.opt3value, a.gift_name, a.gift_file, a.gift_s_file, a.saleprice, a.saleflag, a.hotflag, a.hotcode, a.hotprice, a.price, a.term, a.point, a.pointflag, a.pointorder, a.content, a.html_check, a.couple1, a.couple2, a.couple3, a.regdate, a.cnt, a.sort, a.delflag, b.name   
order by a.regdate desc limit 12";
```

Your actual result is lost, because you have had it stored in `$row_object` which then you overwrite with the result of `mysql_fetch_object()`.

Comment: Thanks Lanzz~ I solved with Zagor23. But the other problem is "$actual_row_count" output "0". Is there any problem near "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.*, ..." ?

Comment: You should probably post a new question about it, and post your current code. In the code posted in your question, you never execute the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` query.