# MySQL Error message thrown attempting to do a JOINed query

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

Here is code:

```
$result=mysql_query("
SELECT items.items_id, 
COUNT(ratings.item_id) AS TotalRating,
AVG(ratings.rating) AS AverageRating
FROM 'items'
LEFT JOIN ratings ON (ratings.item_id = items.items_id)
WHERE ratings.item_id = '{$item_id}' ;");

echo "Error message = ".mysql_error();

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $output[]=$row;
}
```

Here is error:

```
Error message = You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''items' LEFT JOIN ratings ON (ratings.item_id = items.items_id) WHERE ' at line 4
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/k/i/c/kickinglettuce/html/Kickinglettuce/ratethis/get_ratings.php on line 38
null
```

I have confirmed that $item_id is the correct response based on an echo statement.

Comment: Use back quotes around items, \`items\`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the table `items` in SINGLE QUOTES (') instead of BACKTICKS(`).

Comment: That was it, marking you correct! (when the time allows it)

Comment: I hope you've called mysql_real_escape_string on $item_id, otherwise you are open for SQL injection.

Comment: Yes I have made sure of that. I have $item = $database->escape_value(trim($_POST['item']));  with it pointing to a method that does that sort of thing.  EDIT:  Though, $item_id comes after the $item variable is submitteed -- I don't have it protected now that I think about it... even though it's not user input?