# Fetching data from mysql data base in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795746/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result)

I am fetching data from MySQL data base in PHP but it gives error like following:

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/emrapp/surveyList.php on line 97
[]

Below is the query which I am using to select data:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * form survey_Profile where user_Id='".$user_id."' ");
```

Comment: You have an error in your sql syntax. Verify if `survey_Profile` table and `user_Id` field exists

Comment: after `$query` type in `echo mysql_error()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * form survey_Profile where user_Id='".$user_id."' ");
```

to

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from survey_Profile where user_Id='".$user_id."' ");
```

Comment: why downvote the problem was in `form`, i changed it to `from`.

Comment: I saw it now.. sorry.. I switched my vote :)

Comment: yes downvote to "matei mihai"

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: In the future, it's a good idea to make note of what you change, to avoid situations like this where it's extremely hard to spot.  Good catch.  :-)

Comment: @drrcknlsn thanks...for advice...

Answer (score 2):

The cause of tthat error can be that mysql returns False.
You can add an:

```
echo "SELECT * form survey_Profile where user_Id='".$user_id."' ";
```

To see what string is send to mysql, eventualy test it directly in phpmyadmin.
Also, add this code to see the error from mysql:

```
if (mysql_errno()) {
    echo "<br />". mysql_errno(). " : ". mysql_error(). "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because user_id value doesn't exist into your table.

So before executing your resource into mysql_fetch_assoc(), check whether you got matching rows or not.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
//user mysql_fetch_assoc now
}
```

And also you have sql syntax error, in your query replace "form" to "from"